# run javascript only for specific div/s

Tags: javascript, html

How I can run for example this javascript only for specific div/s. Thanks

```
var getAllAnchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
getAllAnchorTags.forEach(function(item){
 var creatLink =item.getAttribute('href')+item.textContent;
 item.setAttribute('href',creatLink)
})
```

in this case for all divs inside wrap div

```
<div id=wrap>
 <div id=tab1>...</div>
 <div id=tab2>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try selectiong your div with `id='wrap'` and then do the `forEach`in all of it's childs

Comment: You want to only select `a` that are descendant of the `div#wrap`???

Comment: yes for all divs under div with id wrap

Answer (score 3):

`querySelector` and `querySelector` accepts all [**CSS Selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) that you can use as CSS rules.

So to select only `a`s that are decsendants of `#tab1` use this:

```
var getAllAnchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('#tab1 a');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your js code based on the `div`'s you want by assigning them some selector class (*ex. `divs-to-work-on`*).

```js
var getAllAnchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('.divs-to-work-on a');
getAllAnchorTags.forEach(function(item) {
  var creatLink = item.getAttribute('href') + item.textContent;
  item.setAttribute('href', creatLink)
})
```

```html
<div id=wrap>
  <div id=tab1 class='divs-to-work-on'>...</div>
  <div id=tab2>...</div>
  <div id=tab3 class='divs-to-work-on'>...</div>
</div>
```

Now your code will only apply to divs that have the class `divs-to-work-on`.

Comment: No worries, if an answer works for you make sure to upvote and accept, for it to be marked at resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can reference to subdivs of specific div, with a way like this

```js
$('#wrap').find('div').each(function(){
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(innerDivId)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=wrap>

wrap

 <div id=tab1>one</div>
 <div id=tab2>two</div>
</div>
```